# Recursive shell call

Tags: bash, shell-script, shell

I have a use case where `Dummy.sh` load data and `fix.sh` fix problematic data and load data again. Here I have to implement retry logic, if fix script is not able solve problem in 3 attempt.

But its going in recursive call where one script is calling another in infinite loop.

Can someone please pinpoint my mistake or suggest any other solution?

**Dummy.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash -x
echo "Load data"
/home/user/etc/fix.sh
```

**fix.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash -x

TEMCOUNTER_TMP=FILE_NAME"_tmp6"

RETRY_C=0

echo $RETRY_C > $TEMCOUNTER_TMP

RETRY_LOGIC=`cat /home/user/etc/$TEMCOUNTER_TMP`
echo $RETRY_LOGIC

while [ $RETRY_LOGIC -le 3 ]
do
/home/user/etc/Dummy.sh
RETRY_LOGIC=`expr $RETRY_LOGIC + 1`
echo $RETRY_LOGIC > $TEMCOUNTER_TMP

done
```

OS : SunOS 5.10 Generic_144488-06 sun4u sparc SUNW,Sun-Fire-V210

PS: I can't implement any logic in Dummy.sh other than calling `fix.sh`

Comment: Is `Dummy.sh` the same as `dmDummy.sh`?  Why are you storing count in a file?

Comment: What is `dmDummy.sh`?

Comment: typo corrected, question updated. @Jesse_b - My counter will always be 0 because Dummy.sh will reset it to 0 by calling fix.sh

Comment: @jackswan So does that answer your question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a couple of issues here. Mainly, you iterate two loops, one inside `fix.sh` (with the while loop) and again recursively by calling back to `dummy.sh`. Also, you reset the counter file back to zero at the start of `fix.sh`, so it is never able to count up. You also have the ordering backwards, so the (recursive) calls to `dummy.sh` occur before you increment the counter.

Assuming only the recursive behaviour is required (since you can change dummy.sh):

## fix.sh

```
#!/bin/bash -x

TEMCOUNTER_TMP=/home/user/etc/FILE_NAME"_tmp6"

RETRY_LOGIC=`cat $TEMCOUNTER_TMP`
echo $RETRY_LOGIC

# Does RETRY_LOGIC have a value?
if [ -z "$RETRY_LOGIC" ]
then
    RETRY_LOGIC=0
    echo 0 > $TEMCOUNTER_TMP
fi

# Try to apply fix
[ $((RANDOM %3)) = 0 ]

# Did it work?
if [ $? = 0 ]
then
    echo "Success!"
    rm $TEMCOUNTER_TMP
    exit
fi

if [ $RETRY_LOGIC -le 3 ]
then
    export RETRY_LOGIC=`expr $RETRY_LOGIC + 1`
    echo $RETRY_LOGIC > $TEMCOUNTER_TMP
    echo "Retrying..."
    /home/user/etc/Dummy.sh
else
    echo "Giving up"
    rm $TEMCOUNTER_TMP
fi
```

Also, check your paths carfully, you prefixed the `TEMCOUNTER_TMP` variable with `/home/user/etc/` in only one location.

Note that the [`export`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bourne-Shell-Builtins.html#index-export) command makes `$RETRY_LOGIC` available in the subsequent attempts, so as long as that variable isn't used elsewhere, you can remove all the lines referring to `TEMCOUNTER_TMP` and it will work the same. If you *do* need the file, note that a [trap](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bourne-Shell-Builtins.html#index-trap) might be better to clean it up afterwards.

Comment: There's a bit of a problem here, because if the whole script needs to be run again the _tmp6 file must be deleted or it'll use the same count again. I'd recommend using an exported (environment) variable instead -- that way it'll only be inherited by subprocesses of that particular run. (But there's a warning: changes to the variable essentially inherit down the process tree, but not up. I don't *think* that'll a problem here...)

Comment: @GordonDavisson Right, I did miss that. Assuming `fix.sh` does some work, it could delete the temp file and exit if successful, or continue retrying if needed. I agree, exporting the variable should work cleanly and would automatically unset in the calling script (assuming bash, not sh).